# Может ли Django slugify работать со строками Unicode?

Tags: unicode, django

Я пытаюсь преобразовать ссылку, заданную кириллицей, с помощью slugify. В итоге получаю пустую строку.

```
<a href="{{cirillic|slugify}}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код функции `slugify` из исходника `trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py`.

```
def slugify(value):
    """
    Normalizes string, converts to lowercase, removes non-alpha characters,
    and converts spaces to hyphens.
    """
    import unicodedata
    value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', value).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    value = unicode(re.sub('[^\w\s-]', '', value).strip().lower())
    return mark_safe(re.sub('[-\s]+', '-', value))
```

Как видно, все множество символов уникода не поддерживается.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую воспользоваться работой Ю. Юревича:
[pytils](https://github.com/j2a/pytils)
То что доктор прописал.